# How do I install geopandas into miniconda?

Tags: python-3.x, gis, geopandas, miniconda

Trying to install geopandas using:

```bash
conda install geopandas
```

but keep receiving the errors:

[image: miniconda errors image]

is there something I'm doing wrong here? can't seem to install geopandas at all.

Comment: when asking about errors, please always include the full error message, even if it's gross, and copy-paste it as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) rather than as an image. stack overflow asks that we not upload images of errors, data, code, logs, etc for a [variety of reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

geopandas has a ton of dependencies, so it's easy to encounter low-level conflicts when installing into an existing environment, especially when you have a mix of channels. It's best to install into a new environment, and to specify a channel, as well as to install all the packages you want to use with it at the same time, e.g.:

```bash
conda create -n mygeoenv -c conda-forge python=3.9 \
    geopandas xarray pandas ipython pip scipy numpy \
    matplotlib cartopy fiona holoviews rasterio
```